# Filter apply concept with high performance and in fast way in android

Tags: android

i am new to android and having a requirement to apply filter effect to the bitmap image.so,before i start with some basic effect like sepia to the bitmap image but the processing of image while applying is taking too much time(waiting time is more).for filter effect i had followed some link:

[link 1 for filter effect](http://xjaphx.wordpress.com/2011/06/21/image-processing-photography-sepia-toning-effect/)

[for the grayscale effect](http://xjaphx.wordpress.com/2011/06/21/image-processing-grayscale-image-on-the-fly/)

[for highlight effect](http://xjaphx.wordpress.com/2011/06/20/image-processing-highlight-image-on-the-fly/)

as u go to link will find many more effect but all the effect taking much time in order to process the image,so on failing to achieve the fast performance again give a try for new concept of filter apply in bitmap image and on search in google play found one app **Instagram** which is also applying effect on image only but performance is good and fast in nature.so can anyone tell me what concept they are using in order to achieve the performance.Thanks for any reply.

Comment: Have you tried the [Aviary SDK](http://www.aviary.com/android)? I use it in two apps and it's pretty fast. Of course mileage varies from device to device. But it's free. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Two efficient ways:

1. Port your code to Use low level algorithms, i.e. a native C library or RenderScript.
2. Use an online web service to do it for you.